# How to update YouTube video with an edited version?

Tags: youtube

I often need to edit my video and update the new version on YouTube, but on the same address.

It seems not possible, so is there a way maybe to create some automatic redirection feature from old to new address?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It’s not actually possible to upload new versions and “update” a video clip on YouTube.

Here are my best practice tips for updating a video:

- Upload your update video as a new video
- Tag it the same way as the original, paying some attention to improving the tags at the same time.
- Use a similar description as the original, again taking the chance to improve it during the process
- Add it as a video comment to the original
- Add an annotation to the old video with a message saying it’s no longer up to date and give a link to the new version
- Promote the new version in all the ways you would normally promote a new video

Why is that best practice?

By following the above best practice you don’t lose your total “views” or the position of that video in search results. At the same time you provide useful and relevant information to people who happen to view the old video clip - you give them a link to a newer version. You’ve helped them. You’ve used the ecosystem of the web in a much better way than just deleting the old, out of date, video.

Comment: dramos, thanks for your step by step explanation. I agree, this is the best solution.

Comment: or you can simply use vimeo (you can upload a new video, it keeps the same URL, views, comments)

Comment: Is it possible to copy the subtitles from the old version to the new one?